# How to Submit Certificate Request from Red Hat to Windows CA?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, redhat, certificate, openssl

My Following Setup:

`Windows Server 2008 AD with CA`

`Redhat Workstation Joined to AD`

I have used Openssl to generate a certificate request to be sent to the CA

`openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout domain.key -out domain.csr`

but how can I submit the request using command line for Red hat?, I'm aware of the window's version command which is

`certreq -submit domain.csr`

Is there a Linux Version of this? I'm trying out Auto-enrollment

I'm aware that I can use the Web Enrolment Page to submit my request, but I'm in a command line environment I don't have access to a browser. and Manually transferring the request with thumb drive is not an option either.

Please enlighten me on this matter. Thanks!!

`yum install elinks` is a good alternative, but is there another command line way? it should be useful for scripting to automate the task

`winexe` Great tool! Using this I understand the concept idea so by generating a certificate in a shared   secure location between the Red Hat Machine and Windows Machine, and issuing the `certreq` commands remotely from the Red hat machine to the windows machine to generate the certificate. I'll test it out in my test environment again later.

but is there a standard industry practice out of the box solution? that anyone is aware of?

Comment: `yum install elinks`. Now you have a Javascript-capable text only browser.

Comment: Perhaps transfer the CSR to a server using some method.  Then use [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) and powershell or your favorite tool from Windows CLI to submit the request and retrieve the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-domain devices, [Network Device Enrollment Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755273.aspx) is often the prefered solution, since it allows auto renewal once set up.

Please have a look at this Technet Wiki article: [Network Device Enrollment Service (NDES) in Active Directory Certificate Services (AD CS)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9063.network-device-enrollment-service-ndes-in-active-directory-certificate-services-ad-cs.aspx) describing how to set up and use NDES

Comment: I'll give this a try at my simulation lab :) Thanks for your input and everyone else here!

Answer (score 0):

Install [certmonger](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Certmonger) and [cepces](https://github.com/openSUSE/cepces), then modify /etc/cepces/cepces.conf for your environment. For a typical configuration, you'll just need to set the `server` parameter to the dns name of your Windows CA.

The rpm spec is supposed to run a script that adds the CA to certmonger. If not, then add it with `getcert add-ca -c cepces -e /usr/libexec/certmonger/cepces-submit`.

Then you can request your certificate, for example:

```
# getcert request -c cepces -T Machine -I MachineCertificate -k /etc/pki/tls/private/machine.key -f /etc/pki/tls/certs/machine.crt
New signing request "MachineCertificate" added.
```